# Check if any textbox has data then do something

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

A `groupbox` has several `Textbox` bounded from database using `ExecuteReader`
now I want to do is if there is only one `textbox` is not empty then make all `Textbox` are read only

`ExecuteReader` return data not like `ExecuteNonQuery` which returns number of rows retrieved so I cannot get any advantage of it

any other suggestion ?

Comment: Could you show your code to us?

Comment: Your ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery have nothing to do with this.  Just loop through your TextBoxes in the GroupBox, and if one is empty, make them all ReadOnly.

Comment: Please be sure to tag with the UI technology you are using. I would guess `winforms`, but I'm not sure. Please also provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
var textBoxes = groupbox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

if (textBoxes.Any(tb => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)))
{
    foreach (var t in textBoxes)
    {
        t.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that what I really need by the way I like it when it was in one single line of code :P thank a lot my master all the respect

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
 {
    // Do something...
 }
```

Comment: This question is tagged with `c#`, answering with jQuery is not likely a good idea...

Comment: @DManokhin this will work only with one textbox I am looping on all textbox within groupbox and if ANY is NOT null then make all read only

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer: enumerate the controls in the groupbox, test if they are edits, if so check if there is any text in the edits.. like so

```
foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
  if (c is TextBox)
    if (((TextBox)c).Text.Length>0)
      {        
        // there is one textbox with text
        // .. do something, like disabling textboxes ..
        break;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through your text boxes like this (using Linq):

```
// Collection of all text boxes
var textBoxes = groupbox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
// Check if one text box is not empty
bool hasText = false;
foreach (TextBox tb in textBoxes)
    hasText |= !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text);
// Set all text boxes to read only
if (hasText)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in textBoxes) tb.ReadOnly = true;
}
```